# Plausible explanation for how human beings might travel the multiverse (assuming other universes separate from our own exist)

Tags: science-fiction

Edit: Let me first thank all of you for being patient with me (I’m by no means a physicist) and for answering my question. This is an update to my previous question. I’ve done some research and to the best of my knowledge the idea that multiple universes could exist is a result of cosmic inflation and the principles of uncertainty in quantum mechanics. Basically (as I understand it) the idea is that during cosmic inflation after the Big Bang due to these uncertainties in quantum mechanics different regions of space time began their ‘Hot Big Bang’ period at different intervals. Thus the gap between universes is the result of the continued inflation of the universe after this happens. So my new question is: could we not just travel there via space? Grant it would be very difficult considering space is still inflating making the distance between universes farther and farther as time passes. But let’s say we use a little handwaving and make it so the teleportation of organic matter is possible or we create a wormhole that won’t collapse almost immediately upon formation and won’t kill us. I’m trying to fill the gaps with as much actual science as possible and whatever is still vastly unknown can be filled in with pseudoscience. Thanks again.

Comment: Typo in the title. Not over, other. My mistake.

Comment: This question is better suited for the [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! Science apart, do you realize that probably most of these universes could be devoid of life or inhabited by dinosaurs that were never wiped from earth? How do you plan to sort these useless universes?

Comment: @Mr. Smith - Typo fixed. I'm pretty sure you can do this yourself in future by clicking on *edit* near the bottom left of your question.

Comment: @ kikirex - presumably the nearest ones will be nearest if you get my drift. A small step to one side will just change things slightly.

Comment: I need to dig to find an answer to this, but I believe I've written one.  The answer was "you can't."  Science does not yet have any concept of what would permit traveling to a parallel universe.  One of the defining charactaristics of a universe is that everything which affects it is found in the universe.  Even QM's Many Worlds Interpretation, when held to its mathematical roots, doesn't permit this.

Comment: Some suggest there are many bubble universe each with unique fundamental physical constants and they rarely interact with each other, but once they do... Big Bang! I'm pretty sure that's sound cool but neither of us would want that, right? Wormhole might be the only bridge to crossover but currently no solution to even allow a particle go through unscathed also different constant means it would not be an exact copy of u and me...

Comment: "How do I X?" questions are very susceptible to being too broad (a book is needed to justify the answer) or primarily opinion-based (the OP can't justify the selection of a best answer).  SE's Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good answer, but there is some prior art for this. Charles Stross wrote a rather good book called Empire Games which heavily features inter-universe travel as a plot point (several alternate earths and their political and military interactions with one another), And (more well known) the Long Earth books by Terry Pratchett and Stephen Baxter feature an infinity of empty earths being colonised by humanity.

Comment: We would not know how this would work, science based, because the whole discussion (collapse of probability wave function through observation versus branching into multiple universes at the moment of observation) is a bit metaphysical. See also this: [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6096/arguments-for-and-against-many-worlds] on Physics StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

**It's almost certainly not possible to provide a plausible scientific explanation**

I'm afraid that (especially with the science based tag) the answer will be that there is no plausible explanation for how human beings might travel the multiverse.

I am very sure that (like the [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible) used by Orson Scott Card in "Ender's Game" to communicate instantly across any distance via quantum entanglement) the idea you can hop between universes is nothing more than a literary device based on junk science arising from poor (or unfortunate) choice of words when explaining the physics to laymen.

That it belongs in the realm of fantasy & has nothing to do with any real (or merely "hard") science.

That said, I'd guess this is an idea you're as attached to as I was to quantum communication, so suspect you'll be resistant to my answer & want "proof" (as I did for why the ansible couldn't work).

But it took me a lot of very frustrating research & reading before I fully understood enough about quantum entanglement to know that the idea it could be used for communication was rubbish & I really don't want to put myself through all that *again* just to provide someone else with proof :)

So I suggest you field a question in the physics stack exchange to get your answers.

**But that said how about this**

Time travel.

Go with the idea the past is fixed (hot tub time machine played with this idea I think).

So (when someone invents a time machine) every time anyone goes to the "past" they create a new alternative timeline (one where an older version of themselves just appeared out of nowhere) & as long as the "wormhole" stays open while they're there they can step back into their own timeline.

> But if the wormhole closes while they're in the past there's absolutely no way to reconnect the two alternate realities, because every time you open one of these time gates it creates a new alternative timeline.

This means nothing they do in the (other) past effects their present.

> So they can bring people & things back with them & they won't disappear from history in their own timeline, which means a short wormhole back gets you your doppelgangers with no need to explain how they manage to tune into an appropriately similar alternate world to find one.

Now you just have to work out the equally improbable mechanics of how to build a time machine.

Comment: I fully understand. I’m not that attached to the idea, though I would appreciate any alternatives you could think that are close to what I originally had in mind or at least any deviations that could be a substitute. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Smith I honestly can't think of any, all the novels I've read to date that use this device (most of which I've thoroughly enjoyed) simply employ large quantities of handwavium with an occasional dollop of techno babble, which is what I'm guessing you're trying to avoid, my best suggestion is still to ask in physics stack exchange, with luck you'll get someone telling you the idea is silly with some suitably impressive jargon you can repurpose as techno babble to disguise your own handwavium with.

Comment: Why would time travel be any more plausible than, well, anything else?

Comment: @Mołot : I refer you to the last line of my "answer" : which clearly states it's not :p

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not proper multiverse, but multi simulated universe, with a central control mechanic. Not that it matter.
2. The central mechanic control how information pass from one universe to another. It is somewhat similar to "type cast" in programming, where there are similar type in other universe that can "simulate activity" of this information
3. The material part of human in one universe do not travel, but they get sensor (eye, touch...) information from that other universe, and their command (movement of body) pass to that other universe. Give feeling similar to how you dream.
4. The tech required: information about how to communicate with central mechanic and with other universe. No need for material movement.

Answer (score 1):

As you implied, there is no hard science answer. I can tell you some ideas that I think about sometimes which may have similarities in essence. String theory mixed with modulation. If your character can figure out how to modulate the frequency of string vibrations and create new harmonics the result may cause a disruption in the fabric of the space-time continuum. This technique might be used in conjunction with a device to simultaneously match the characters own string vibrations with another universes string vibrations.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes very simple if we are right in our understanding that our universe could be a simulated universe rather than a real one.

Because all manner of simulations are possible it is even possible to have simulations of universes being emulated inside currently running simulations.

(such as when we run gravity simulations etc).

So the chances of being a simulation are much higher than the chances of being in the real thing.

So in this case travel to the multiverse might only involve transfer of data.

Any violations of the laws of physics could also be conveniently explained by the changes data values while the simulation is running.

For instance walking on water could be fixed by running the code

If height < 0 then set height = 0 and the object would appear to be floating or levitating.

Answer (score 0):

Travelling the multiverse is currently magic because our physic and mathematical models are not up to the task of adequately representing fifth or higher order dimensions required to plot an exit point and return safely.  So you could do a cheat and "find" an ancient artifact that acts as a portal (tv shows such as Sliders, Twilight Zone or Stargate SG1).  Were humans able to build such a device that could breach the veil/barrier it would require a ridiculous amount of energy and would not be something portable in scale.  The computations would require the use of a super computer or several working together.

Comment: "our physic and mathematical models are not up to the task" suggest it's something that can be done when we've studied the problem a bit, I think that's misleading & that it's more a case of "physics clearly states it (_travelling_ the multiverse) doesn't exist & never will". It's not that it's _currently_ magic, it will always be magic.